# Is there a way to dynamically display/hide columns

Tags: apache-superset

Is there a way to dynamically display/hide columna bases on JINJA conditionals or anything similar?

So there is a SQL Editor query that I have converted to a dataset that is supposed to do some SUMs and output for example revenue per months however, I also have date filtration on top of it so then if I want to track 10 months of results by having those columns, if the filter is only for the last 2 months those results will come out empty.

If necessary and/or is unclear, I can attach images to exemplify what I mean.